# Lua pattern matching a number format and not capturing earlier numbers

Tags: lua

I want to capture resolutions and refresh rate outputs from `xrandr -q`. Specifically, these numbers are formatted as `xx.xx` or `xxx.xx`, where there will always be 2 numbers after a decimal point, but sometimes 2 or 3 numbers before it as well. I want to capture each value individually to be able to store them for later use.

4 lines of typical command output would look like this:

```
   3440x1440     59.97 +  99.98*   49.99  
   2560x1440     59.95  
   2560x1080     60.00    59.94  
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00
```

I've been able to get the resolution using `string.match(xrandr[i], "^.-%s(%d.-x.-%s)")` where xrandr is an array containing each line of command output. My current attempt for getting the refresh rates individually looks like this: `string.gmatch(xrandr[i], "%s.-(%d.-%..-%d%d)")`. This almost works, but for every resolution, it captures both the resolution and the first refresh rate together, and then captures any following separately. When I try to print the intentionally captured resolution followed by each of its supported refresh rates, it looks like this:

```
3440x1440 
3440x1440     59.97
99.98
49.99
2560x1440 
2560x1440     59.95
```

Where the resolution is captured, but then it's captured again with the first refresh rate. Instead I'd like to get this:

```
3440x1440 
59.97
99.98
49.99
2560x1440 
59.95
```

So how can I avoid re-capturing the resolution while also getting each refresh rate invididually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your patterns are way to complicated.

Resolution: `"%d+x%d+"

`%d`  any digit

`%d+` one or more digits

`x`  character x

Refresh rates: `"%d+%.%d+"`

`%.` a dot (escaped magic character `.` with `%`, otherwise `.` means any character)

In one go:

```
local a = "1234x5678 12.34 56.78"

for match in a:gmatch("[0-9x.]+") do print(match) end
```

`[0-9x.]` is a class of characters. it matches any occurance of digits `0` to `9`, `.` or `x`

So `"[0-9x.]+"` matches any sequence of digits that may also contain a `.` or an `x`

Comment: That works amazingly, thanks. I guess 15 minutes of reading docs didn't help too much, but would you be able to explain what these patterns are doing exactly?

Comment: @Raspberry-Jam i suggest giving this page a read, https://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:understanding_lua_patterns